Not sound in Ubuntu 24.04
I just bought an HP Envy x360 2-in-1 laptop 15 ew1xxx with Windows 11 installed. I decided to install Ubuntu 24.04. I noticed that the sound is not working. Can someone help me?

inxi -A
Audio:
Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-48-generic status: kernel-api
Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active

Update to kernel 6.11 or higher, the sound (speakers) should work well now. But beware the external monitors seem not to work from 6.11 onwards ....
